# Alternative for onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So i am making app in Android studio(java) and i am using image picker from https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker. Is there a way to get result from image picker without using deprecated method
`onActivitiyResult()` ? I have read https://www.tutorialguruji.com/android/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative/ this article but i am not quite sure how to use image picker in this context.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create a Uri (a path from where you want User to select the image), then you can use this Uri to pass to the intent and it will directly go to that Uri. Here, due to Storage Access Changes on Android 10 onwards we can't directly get the path to root directory, so here we pass the uri to get all the images present in External Volume of Device. And in Android 9 below we can directly access Root Directory, so the Uri is different.

```
binding.imageCamera.setOnClickListener { v ->

Uri uri; 

if (isSdk29andUp()){

    uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);

}  else {

    uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

}

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uri);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    pickPhotoLauncher.launch(intent);
}

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> pickPhotoLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                    Intent data = result.getData();

                    // Here the data will be Uri.
            
                }
            }
        });
}
```